# How do i configure WebLogic 8.1 to use a specific JRE / JDK on my development machiine

Tags: weblogic, java

How do i configure WebLogic 8.1 to use a specific JRE / JDK on my development machine. I realized that it is using hot spot and i would like to change it to run on JRockit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the JAVA_VENDOR setting in the setDomainEnv.sh/.cmd file (depending whether you are running a Linux or Windows box).

Adding/changing the following lines to the start of your setDomainEnv file should work:

set JAVA_VENDOR=BEA

set BEA_JAVA_HOME=(path to your jrockit installation, e.g. c:\BEA\jrockit)

Now you should start the server. You can monitor, in the console (stdout), the indication about which Java version is being used:

**starting weblogic with Java version:

java version "1.6.0_05"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_05-b13)
BEA JRockit(R) (build R27.6.0-50_o-100423-1.6.0_05-20080626-2105-windows-ia32, compiled mode)**

It is also possible to do it during the configuration wizard, when you are adding a domain, under the Java SDK Selections tab.